# Разбор командной строки.

Tags: qt, c++

Пишу программу на С++/Qt. Требуется максимально быстро и просто реализовать разбор параметров командной строки. Возможно использование сторонних библиотек. Интересуют плюсы и минусы каждого способа.

Дополнительно:

1. Возможно потребуются ключи, принимающие несколько аргументов (например, список файлов). Т.е., например, `program -i file1 file2 file 3 -o catenated_output`
   `file1 file2 file3` - должны ассоциироваться с `-i`, а не быть просто какими-то произвольными аргументами.
2. По возможности хочу пользоваться продвинутыми строковыми классами типа `QString` или хотя бы `std::string`

Comment: Хм, а почему тогда не `-i file1,file2,file3`?

Comment: Ну, можно и так. А как быть с вариантом, что запятая может быть элементом наименования файла? Тогда `-i "file1","file2","file3"`?

Comment: Угу, то же и с пробелом в имени файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще.

1. [qgetopts](https://code.google.com/p/qgetopts/)
2. [QxtCommandOptions](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.5/class_qxt_command_options.html)
3. [qtargparser](https://code.google.com/p/qtargparser/)
4. [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: сам спросил, сам ответил, сам принял - новая методика?:)

Comment: Новая методика для чего? Все равно попугаев за это не дают, а подробного хорошего ответа все равно нет.

Comment: @gecube, разборщиков командной строки много, я сам написал несколько разным командам, но (сапожник без сапог?) почти всегда в каждой новой программе сам разбираю их "с нуля".

Почему?

По моему опыту если синтаксис ключей совсем тривиальный, то быстрей и проще написать их разбор влет, чем вспомнить, как пользоваться одним из разборщиков. А в сложном случае все равно ничего подходящего не найдется (с изучением за разумное время).

Вы что, main-ы каждый день пишете? Тут как с make. Простые вещи помнишь и не задумываясь пишешь, а что-то хитро-компактное... И в нем еще через полгода разбираться..

Comment: @avp, мне кажется, что лучше опереться на какую-либо готовую библиотеку, чем ваять велосипед каждый раз заново. Да и если какие-либо глюки выползут, то в случае библиотеки их можно централизованно поправить, чем каждый случай лечить отдельно. К тому же, компьютер ведь должен облегчать существование человека...

Comment: @gecube, это весьма распространенная точка зрения и она, безусловно, имеет право на жизнь.

--

Но, подумайте (не знаю, насколько цифры применимы к программированию, инженерии и т.п.), известно, что в спорте (да и управлении автомобилем) для совершенного овладения техническим приемом, надо его правильно сделать (на тренировках) 3000 раз (но не более 100 раз в день). А чтобы приобрести этот навык навсегда - 10000 раз. Разумеется, если у человека есть определенный уровень физических способностей к этому делу.

--

Так что, просто пишите больше разного кода (тренируйтесь).

Comment: @avp, если программирование - самоцель, то Вы безусловно правы. Но как пример - Вы же не будете писать стандартные контейнеры заново? Я б не стал. Более того - даже если есть какие-то специфические требования к быстродействию, я бы сначала сделал прототип программы на стандартных элементах, а потом уже их специализировал под себя (благо шаблоны - это удобно).

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал старый добрый [GNU getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Кстати, вот [тут](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) рекомендуются и другие альтернативы от GNU.

Ещё советуют [boost::program options](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/), но я лично не пробовал.

Comment: Еще варианты?

Comment: @gecube: добавил ещё :-)

Comment: Ещё такое есть - [qtargparser](https://code.google.com/p/qtargparser/)

Comment: @KoVadim: вы опередили @gecube на 20 секунд :-)

Comment: @VladD, кажется, что буст будет самый правильный вариант. В нем можно и std::string использовать, и можно всякие хитрости с аргументами делать.
@KoVadim, у qtargparser, пожалуй, только одно преимущественно - это очень маленький инклюд.

Comment: boost хорош, только если используются другие классы с этой библиотеки. Но вот boost::program options нуждается в внешней dll/so. В некоторых случаях это может быть очень большой минус.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, QXT тоже нужно отдельно линковать... Я б не сказал, что это фатально. Главное - функционал.

Answer (score 0):

**QCommandLineParser**

The QCommandLineParser class provides a means for handling the command line options.